# wrapping a C++20 function that takes either a string or a char as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

In C++20 we can use a `FixedString` to pass string literals as template parameters:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N> struct FixedString {
    char data[N];
    template <std::size_t... I> constexpr FixedString(const char (&s)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>): data{s[I]...} {}
    constexpr FixedString(const char (&s)[N]): FixedString(s, std::make_index_sequence<N>()) {}
};

template <FixedString s> void print() {
    std::cout << '"' << s.data << '"';
}
template <char c> void print() {
    std::cout << '\'' << c << '\'';
}

int main() {
    print<"hello">(); // this works
    print<'h'>(); // this works
}
```

However, if I try to write a function that wraps the `print` function, I get an error if I try to call it with a string literal.

```
template <auto x> void print_wrapped() {
    std::cout << '(';
    print<x>();
    std::cout << ')';
}

int main() {
    print_wrapped<'h'>(); // this works
    print_wrapped<"hello">(); // error
}

// <source>: In function 'int main()':
// <source>:25:28: error: no matching function for call to 'print_wrapped<"hello">()'
//    25 |     print_wrapped<"hello">(); // error
//       |                            ^
// <source>:17:24: note: candidate: 'template<auto x> void print_wrapped()'
//    17 | template <auto x> void print_wrapped() {
//       |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
// <source>:17:24: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
// <source>:25:28: error: '"hello"' is not a valid template argument for type 'const char*' // because string literals can never be used in this context
//    25 |     print_wrapped<"hello">(); // error
//       |                            ^
// Compiler returned: 1
```

How do I write a single version of `print_wrapped` that takes either a string literal or a char as a template argument and dispatches to `print` based on that argument?

Comment: How about adding a constructor to `FixedString` that accepts a single character? Also using `std::index_sequence` is unnecessary here, a plain loop would work equally well.

Answer (score 3):

The **problem** is that when you pass the string literal `"hello"` as a template argument in `print_wrapped<"hello">()` the template parameter `x` is deduced as `const char*`, but the c++ standard doesn't allow a string literal as an non-type template argument for `const char*`. Basically the problem is the same as in `template<const char*> void f(); int main(){f<"hello">();}` .

You can use [user defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) to explicitly make clear while passing the non-template argument that you're passing a `FixedString` as shown below. With this instead of writing `"hello"` we would write `"hello"_S`.

```
template <FixedString s>
constexpr auto operator""_S() {
    return s;
}

int main() {
    print_wrapped<'h'>();        // works as before
    print_wrapped<"hello"_S>(); // works now 
//-----------------------^^----->note the suffix 
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/59xrasa8r)

Comment: I'd like to avoid the added noise of the user defined literal.

Comment: @eyelash There is no "noise". It makes clear that you want to pass a `FixedString` not a string literal. A string literal is not the same as a `FixedString`.

Comment: @eyelash Updated. I usually prefer when we write code that is explicit than implicit.

Comment: +1 If I can make a suggestion, you should clarify the answer in the sense that the op wanted to call print_wrapper<FixedString{...}>() but was instead calling print_wrapper<char*>(). Giving this page as ref might also be helpful to understand the issue discussed here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters